# Laravel Custom Registration Route/Logic

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to overwrite Laravel 5.2's `public function postRegister()` in my Auth controller.

I start by changing the route:

```
Route::post('/auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegisterI');
```

In my Auth controller, I now have this new `postRegisterI()` method as oppose to relying on the foundational `postRegister()`. But my changes in this new method don't seem to apply?

Is it still pointing to `postRegister()` for some reason? My AuthController looks like this:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    public function postRegisterI(Request $request)
    {
        return print_r($request);
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }

        //Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));
        $this->create($request->all());
        //return redirect($this->redirectPath());
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:2',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

For example in my ajax requests to `/auth/register/` it never echoes out my returns as I indicate and it also keeps trying to redirect me to `/home`. I'm doing this because instead of passing `/auth/register` a form, I'm passing it a Javascript array with data to not only create a user (email, password, etc) but also an application that the user needs to join.

Eventually, I would like to create the Application model with that data right when the User is created, but right now I'm not sure that my function is even being called correctly!

**EDIT:** So, it looks like the **`__construct()`** function is causing the issue... should I get rid of it? I don't understand why I need to comment that out to get my returns from `postRegisterI()`?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that your new route is declared before the call to `Route::auth()`. Otherwise, Laravel will ignore your addition, and will always call the one that Easy Auth comes with.
Second. Why do you want to override a method using another method with a different name? By simply creating a method postRegister in your AuthController you are automatically overriding the method that resides in the Trait.  So you shouldn't be worrying about having to add an additional method and route. Unless you want to have a multi-authentication system, and in this case, this wouldn't be the correct solution.

Another thing, for ajax request, make sure you validate that the request is of type ajax:

```
if ($request->ajax()){
//Code here
return response()->json([],200);
}
```

This controller is designed to check registration rules, create an user, and redirect to the redirection path. It is not designed for ajax handling, thus, you will need to add code for it

Comment: Sorry what do you mean, where is the call to Auth::routes()?

Comment: I just updated, I meant: `Route::auth()`. Which is what you use to register all the Easy Auth routes in your routes.php. In Laravel 5.3 is  `Auth::routes();`

Comment: I don't have any `Route::auth()` declared in my routes.php... any other ideas as to why it is still pointing to the old function? Do I need to refresh some config file?

Comment: Maybe there is some cache like in the config files?

Comment: You shouldn't be using cache in development, but if you are, you can run artisan optimize to give it a refresh. Did you cache the routes?

Comment: Well I did the config cache clear as well as optimize as it seems to be working now! Thanks for the tip! How do I disable cache though, given that I am in development?

Comment: Also, the first line of my `postRegisterI()` is a `return print_r($request);` but I don't see that in the network request in the chrome dev tools, I just get an empty response?

Comment: You should have cache off by default in development, since you cache cleared, you should be good now. I'm not sure exactly why you are getting an empty response, but remember that this controller is not configured for ajax. You can expect responses when you do `return response()->json([json here], 200);`. then is when you can use the dev tools.

Comment: Grrrrr it turns out clearing the cache did not help, it still keeps going to the old method because upon refreshing my tokens I get the same `/home/ redirection... I'm running out of ideas...

Answer (score -1):

maybe this topic will help you [custom register](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-do-i-post-a-form-in-laravel-5-using-ajax?page=1)